# Modification to question is not clearly tracked

Tags: discussion, editing

Today (18th Dec 2019), I've noticed that a 2-year old question was modified by a non-moderator user but I could not clearly see what was actually edited.

From home, the question is indicated to have been modified 1 hour ago.
[image]

Opening the [question detail](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154033/lightning-component-in-list-view-button) does show that it was active today, but last edit was done back 2016.
No new answer was added, no new comments, no edits on existing answer.

Am I missing something here ?

Or is it because I do not have enough privilege to see what has changed ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message "Modified by `<username other than Community>`", with no visible changes to the post, often means that moderation activity took place. That action might have come via the review queues or via one of the three elected moderators.

For example, it's very common for late answers (posted long after the question) to be removed as not meeting answer expectations, often due to being a follow-up question. That yields this indicator on the question post's listing on the main page, which remains "bumped" even after the answer causing it to be bumped as been removed.

Comment: Ah so there was a moderation activity then which explains the modification. thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Typically when I see these posts, I see that it was modified by the `Community` user:

[image: Modified by Community User]

By my estimation, 95-99% of edits by this user are "bumping" a post to get it more attention. Specifically on the question you asked about, there have been a great many "bumps".

[image: Bumped by Community User]

You can read more **[on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578)**.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. for the question I asked about, a different username than "community" was mentioned for the edit today and it fits David Reed explanation that this was part of moderation activity.